# Save UIImage with highest possible quality in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I saved `UIView` as `UIImage` using following code:

```
extension UIView{

    var screenshot: UIImage{

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        self.layer.renderInContext(context!)
        let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return screenShot
    }
}
```

And I saved the output Image using following function:

```
func saveImage (image: UIImage, path: String ) -> Bool{
    let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let result = pngImageData!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    return result
}
```

Then I retrieve the image in different view as follows:

```
func loadImageFromPath(path: String) -> UIImage? {

    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)

    if image == nil {
        print("missing image at: \(path)")
    }
    return image
}
```

However The quality of picture reduced! Could anyone help me how can I keep maximum possible quality for `UIImage`?

Comment: PNG format should not affect the image quality. Can you present a pair of original and "damaged" images to demonstrate quality reduction?

Comment: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0)`

Comment: @originaluser2 Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I want